# Is UI testing possibile with Appium by using selenium webdriver with Java for Android native application

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

Is UI testing like font size,color, alignment is possible with Appium by using selenium webdriver with Java  for Android native application.

Answer (score 0):

You are saking if a functional testing tool can do ui testing. First you have to understand the Appium is s functional testing tool.

But some level of ui testing is possible with Appium. For example you can test the alignment of an element relatively to another object.

For colour and font i dont see a straight forward way of testing. For colourand font testing you can use appium to run your scripts and a screencasting application to cast your device into desktop and fire sikuli image recognizing commands.

Comment: Can u pls tell how to check the alignment??

Comment: you can select a base element and get the X, Y coordinate of the web element. `X = baseelement.getLocation().getX()`, `Y = baseelement.getLocation().getY()`. And for the target elements also you can do the same and compare the coordinates to check the alignments.